# How to design subscription plan(stripe) based permissions in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm building a SaaS product where subscription happens with the integration of Stripe. I have multiple subscription plans and certain APIs are restricted to advanced/premium plans only. How do I build API permissions so that it works well with dynamic plans? Plans can be added or deleted at Stripe's dashboard which gets synced with my backend models. Is there a way to associate certain endpoints to a plan using admin panel without modifying the codebase?

Answer (score 0):

you can write down the custom permission class using restframework in that you can check which type of plat that is, one the basis of that you can raise an exception if the user has permissions or not.

Comment: Plans can be added or deleted. I don't wanna make changes in the code whenever I add/remove a plan. I should be able to associate certain API endpoints to a particular plan using admin panel. Creating  a user group and adding permissions based on group/roles is one option. But I wanted to know if there a better design pattern for this.

Comment: you can take the plan id in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues, and thinking to consider django Group as a Plan with set of permissions. So seems it may be helpfull for you too.
Django user can have different Groups, as user can have different stripe Plans. Group has set of permissions and Plan must have them too.
But I have just started to think on it, so don't know how to attach Plan to group, inerit or make oneToOne relation.

Funny but I was searching for ready implementation of such logic.

Update:
Found this repo, it seems to be usefull.
https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/djstripe/models.py